# Quais são as causas que levam uma session php a expirar?

Tags: php

No php as sessions são uteis pra segurar dados temporariamente. Mas as minhas estão expirando muito rápido (em menos de 15 minutos) e eu ainda não consegui entender o por que.
Meu *session.cache_expire*, de acordo com o phpinfo() está setado pra 240.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você já viu se está setado como segundos ou minutos? Se for segundos, dá 4 minutos... Aumente, e faça o teste

Comment: De acordo com a documentação do php.net é em minutos. E eu testei aqui e ela expira antes desses 4 minutos, inclusive.

Comment: Tentou aumentar o tempo pra ver?

Comment: Tentei agora. Não resolveu.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que alterar o parâmetro `session.cookie_lifetime` mais informações no [site do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

---

Update:

Tenta aumentar também `session.gc_maxlifetime` ex.

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
session_set_cookie_params(3600);
session_start();
```

Comment: Tentei, e mesmo assim ainda não resolveu.

Comment: Você esta usando um shared host? Se for isso a pasta pode estar sendo apagada pelo servidor?

Comment: Estou sim, se for o caso da pasta estar sendo apagada pelo servidor, o que eu poderia fazer para reverter?

Comment: Se der tentar criar um php.ini personalizado e mudar o path da session. Ou abrir um ticket pro suporte.

Comment: Vou tentar, conforme for, notifico aqui do que aconteceu.
Mesmo assim, muito obrigado!